# Format List<Map<String,String>> using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to map an object to json to look like this:

```
 {"MyClass" : 
      [
        {"key" : "value"},
        {"key" : "value"}
      ]}
```

However my code is giving me:

```
{"MyClass" : {
      "list" : {
        "key" : "value",
        "key" : "value"
      }
```

And my code is like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<Map<String,String>> list;

    //getters & setters......
  }
```

And:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map1.put("key", "value");

Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
map2.put("key","value");

List<Map<String,String> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>();
list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);
```

And I am using `ObjectMapper` to map the values. What can I do to get the layout I want?

Comment: the code seems to work, what's the problem? the names don't match?

Comment: it works but not the same format I want. For example, I don't want the name of the list printed

Comment: this is the name of the variable, you can change it to different name or use `@JsonProperty` notation as my example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your code

```
class MyClass  {

    @JsonProperty("MyClass")
    public List<Map<String,String>> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map1.put("key", "value");

        Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map2.put("key","value");

        List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        list.add(map1);
        list.add(map2);

        MyClass d = new MyClass();
        d.list = list;

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(d);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

output

```
{"MyClass":[{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"}]}
```

I used `@JsonProperty` to change the name but you can also change the name of the var from `list` to whatever

Note: this is just draft implementation... don't use **public** class vars, and such...

Comment: I'm not getting that layout on mine, I'm using prettyprinter to print, could that make a difference?

Comment: @user3871995 pretty print effect only the display format not the structure, what do you get when running my example code?